# Regex to detect Javascript In a string

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, xss

I am trying to detect JavaScript in my querystrings value.

I have the following c# code

```
    private bool checkForXSS(string value) 
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"/((\%3C)|<)[^\n]+((\%3E)|>)/I"); 

        if (regex.Match(value).Success) return true; 

        return false; 
    }
```

This works for detecting `<script></script>` tags but unfortunately if there were no tags a match is not reached.

Is it possible for a regex to match on JavaScript keywords and semi-colons etc?

**This is not meant to cover all XSS attack bases.  Just a way to detect simple JS attacks that can be in a string value.**

Thanks

Comment: Ok, and then you must detect the presence of the substring "onmouseover", etc... Read my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520973/regex-to-detect-javascript-in-a-string/1521042#1521042

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nº 1 Rule: Use a whitelist, not a blacklist.

You are preventing one way to do a XSS, not any. To achieve this, you must validate the input against what you should accept as a user input, i.e.

- If you expect a number, validate the input against `/^\d{1, n}$/`
- If you expect a string, validate it against `/^[\s\w\.\,]+$/`, etc...

For further info, start reading the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Mitigation), the [entry at OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29), [webappsec articles](http://projects.webappsec.org/Cross-Site-Scripting) and some random [blog entries written by unknown people](https://blog.codinghorror.com/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks/)

Comment: Sad nobody catch the "unknown people" joke

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty lame way of preventing cross-site scripting attacks.  You need to use a completely different approach: make sure that your user-supplied input is:

1. Validated such that it matches the semantics of the data being gathered;
2. Appropriately quoted every time that it is used to construct expressions to be interpreted by some language interpreter (SQL, HTML, Javascript - even when going to a plain-text logfile). Appropriate quoting completely depends on the output context, and there is no single way to do it.

Comment: I am picking up an existing app where querystrings are put to the page.  I need to check the values for javascript, e.g. alert, function, events etc and HTML.  My above regex checks for tags but not for JS keywords etc.  I want to strip the JS before its put to the page.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to embed javascript.  E.g.

```
  %3Cp+style="expression(alert('hi'))"
```

will make it through your filter.

You probably can't find a magical regexp that will find all JS and that won't reject a lot of valid query strings.

This kind of checking might be useful, but it should only be one part of a defense-in-depth.

Answer (score -5):

It should be enough for you to check if the tag `<script` is present.

```
private bool checkForXSS(string value) 
{
    return value.IndexOf("<script") != -1;
}
```

Comment: False. `onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc. can exist without script tags.

Comment: I can think of a handful of other ways of circumventing this; it is a poor approach.